# 3ds Max Не получается корректно заполнить массив струкрур

Tags: массивы, структуры, 3dsmax

Создаю структуру, например:

```
struct st (  
   public  
   num,  
   str  
)
```

Далее пытаюсь примерно таким способом заполнить массив:

```
arr = #();  
el = st();

el.num = val_1;  
el.str = "str_1";  
append arr el;

el.num = val_2;  
el.str = "str_2";  
append arr el;
```

И получается, что элементы массива arr лишь ссылаются на переменную el, так как оба элементамассива иеют одинаковые значения val_2 и "str_2". Если изменить переменную el, то автоматически всё поменяется и в массиве. Как сделать, чтобы в массив arr добавлялись копии переменной el, а не копии её адреса?

Answer (score 0):

Кажется я нашёл решение.
Вместо строки:

```
append arr el;
```

использую строку:

```
append arr (copy el);
```

Вроде работает, дальше видно будет. Не знаю на сколько так грамотно делать.